# How to config gitignore?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I want to ignore some of my files (/config/environments/production.rb , /webrat.log , /config/database.yml ).  My gitignore:

```
/.bundle
/db/*.sqlite3
/doc/
*.rbc
*.sassc
.sass-cache
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/vendor/bundle
/log/*
/tmp/*
/public/system/*
/coverage/
/spec/tmp/*
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html

/config/environments/production.rb
/config/*.yml
/*.log
```

But this doesn't work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you did is correct. Probably you have already added these files, before making .gitignore.

So Try this

```
git rm -r --cached .   (Note the period at the end.)
git add .
```

Then check whether the files that you put in ignore is still added to the index. Or you could modify them  and check whether they are being tracked.

Answer (score 3):

If those files were already added to the index, you need to remove them first.

```
git rm --cache /config/environments/production.rb
git rm --cache /webrat.log 
git rm --cache /config/database.yml
```

Then the `.gitignore` can work on those files.

Answer (score 1):

If "database.yml" got added to your git repo before you specified it in the ignore
file, I think you have to remove it:

```
git rm config/database.yml
git commit -a -m "Removed database.yml"
```

Then, add database.yml file in your project, will work fine.